# Django autocomplete-light v3 from db

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

I've already make it directly in HTML page with Jquery but I think isn't a good solution due to the big item list. I think it's better have a huge list stored in the db and than autocompile the field in my case.
I want autocompile (with airport name) two field (departure and destination). So in models.py I make two class:

```
class Aero(models.Model):
    departure = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class AirportName(models.Model):
    air_name= models.CharField(max_length=70)
```

I populate the db with 3000 airport (I use AirportName class to do that). Now I would like that when a user start to digit in departure or destination field (in a form), it will appear the possibile match airport list. I read the documentation but I don't understand how do that, maybe I mistake everything.

url.py:

```
url(
    r'^fly-autocomplete/$',
    Fly.as_view(),
    name='fly-autocomplete',
),
```

views.py:

```
class Fly(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):

def get_queryset(self):
    form = AeroForm()
    qs = AirportName.objects.all()
    if self.q:
        qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)
    return qs
```

forms.py:

```
class AeroForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Aero
        fields = ('__all__')
        widgets = {
            'departure': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='fly-autocomplete'),
            'destination': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='fly-autocomplete'),
        }
```

Comment: Are you able to `reverse('fly-autocomplete')` ?

Comment: in url.py I add "from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse" and then "print(reverse('fly-autocomplete'))". In the prompt appear "/fly-autocomplete/"

Comment: OK. Next step: Are you able to do `127.0.0.1:8000/fly-autocomplete/?q=a` ? Or whatever the full url to this URL is.

Comment: No, if I use that link it give me this error:FieldError at /fly-autocomplete/

Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: air_name, id

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/fly-autocomplete/?q=a
Django Version:  1.11
Exception Type:  FieldError
Exception Value:  

Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: air_name, id

Comment: That's because there is no `name` field inside your model. Change to this: `qs = qs.filter(air_name__istartswith=self.q)` and retry.

Comment: Now it work: If I write for example: "127.0.0.1:8000/fly-autocomplete/?q=New York" it will display on page some result so the query works good.  
results 
0 
text "AirportName object"
id "675"
1 
text "AirportName object"
id "676"
2 
text "AirportName object"
id "677"
pagination 
more false

Comment: I insert __str__(self) in the class AirportName to show the airport name so now the result like above is: text "New York, NY - All airports (NYC)"  id "675". What is the next step?

Comment: @nik_m I try to use a Foreign Key for departure. In the html page I was able to see a drop-down menu with all airport name so it load from db the entire airport name list (I made this test to understand if I was able to get information from the db). Anyway I still not understand how query with a text field to autocomplete, it seems not work...